# Как обрезать картинку по заданным координатам?

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Посетил уйму сайтов и пересмотрел тонны кода, но так и не понял, как мне обрезать картинку.

Я сделал все, чтобы картинку можно было ресайзить, крутить и двигать. Все, что мне надо, это просто обрезать картинку.

Мне надо обрезать картинку по координатам (10, 10, 300, 400).

Кто-то знает какие-то решения для этого?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так можно обрезать:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

{ 
    [super viewDidLoad];

```
UIImage *Image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"];

CGRect Rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 300.0, 400.0);

CGImageRef CropImage= CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([Image CGImage],Rect);

self.ImageView.image=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:CropImage];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Не забыть CoreGraphics. Не понял, что вы имели ввиду под координатами.

```
UIImage *image;
CGSize newSize;
newSize.height = 0; //вычислить новую высоту
newSize.width = 0; //вычислить новую ширину
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, FALSE, 0.0);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)]; // вычислить координаты
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```